# Datagrid View cells as Boolean values: Using Datagrid view similar to MS Outlook Meeting Schedular

Tags: c#, winforms, datagrid

I am trying to develop a time sheet similar to Outlook meeting scheduling thing(Picture attached from internet). I have days as rows and time as columns. I am trying to use cells in Datagrid view such that when user select cell corresponding to day and time i get input by this selection (nothing to be displayed in cells, I just want to use selected cell as my input). I have declared columns as Boolean type so that selected cell corresponds to True and un-selected as False.

```
   foreach (DataGridViewColumn column in this.dataGridView1.Columns)
        {
            column.ValueType = typeof(Boolean);
        }
```

However I am not sure how to proceed with this, as I have just declared and not initialized Boolean cells. I am looking a way to initialize cells such that no text appears in cells [blank cells which will be highlighted on selection] and I can just take input based upon selection/non selection of cells.[image]

Answer (score 0):

Since you want the selected cells as input you can use `DataGridView.SelectedCells` ([docs here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.selectedcells.aspx)). From the returned collection you can get the row and column of each selected cell, which in your case maps to day and time.

Here's an example:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataGridViewSelectedCellCollection cells = this.dataGridView1.SelectedCells;

    foreach (DataGridViewTextBoxCell cell in cells)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Selected cell: column: {0}  row: {1}", cell.ColumnIndex, cell.RowIndex);
    }
}
```

Output when I selected a couple cells in the third column:

> Selected cell: column: 2  row: 2
>   Selected cell: column: 2  row: 1

Comment: so you think I shouldn't use cells as Boolean? I was thinking to use cells as boolean and initialize them

Comment: No, I don't think so. Since you just care about the selection state of the cells, `DataGridView` already keeps track of that and makes it accessible to you via `SelectedCells` so I wouldn't keep track of additional state in Booleans.